# Stopped reading google tables (invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF)

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

My integration with Google tables worked successfully for half a year, but today it stopped because of an error
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF

has anyone encountered such an error?

```
 private static Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStream in = SheetsHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/credentials.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new InputStreamReader(in));

    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            clientSecrets, scopes
    ).setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File("tokens"))).setAccessType("offline")//<--the error is here
            .build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    return credential;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace - at the moment we have no idea where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Can you check that the refresh token wasnt revoked.  Just change "user" to something else as a test or delete the file in new java.io.File("tokens").    My guess is your getting an invalid_token error.